# Maven Development Tools/Command Line

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'd like to have some tools in my maven project which I can run from inside my IDE (IntelliJ in my case) but which are not packaged with the application. Pretty much just java classes with a main method, similar to the "test" source root but not meant for testing.

Is there any good lightweight method/best practice for achieving this?

An example for such a task would be to reset some test databases, regenerate certain files based on some 3rd party systems etc, so more like scripting tasks having access to the classpath/data model of the module.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the purpose of such classes?

Comment: Can be basically anything - what I'm using those for right now is e.g. generating some certificates/files for testing, checking or modifying some databases during development, etc.

Comment: @frow -- Does my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

For those internal utility programs that I don't plan to distribute, I put them under `test` (a folder parallel to `src`) with its own class hierarchy that parallels the one under `src`.  And then in my `pom.xml`, I just name `src` as the `sourceDirectory`.  Would this work for your case?

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.xml</include>
                <include>*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
```

P.S. My artifact is a `war` file.  And I use `Eclipse` not `Intellj-idea` but for this question I think it does not matter.